# Creating a custom element from previously defined component

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a working component called `PluginComponent` part of a `PluginsModule` in my project. This project is made up from many other components and modules.

However I'd like to take just the `pluginComponent` and make it a [Custom Element](https://angular.io/guide/elements) so I can redistribute it as a single custom tag and js file.

To achieve this I created an application with `ng generate application` and made the following `app.module.ts` in the new app.

```
import { PluginsModule } from '../../../../src/app/plugins/plugins.module';
import { PluginComponent } from '../../../../src/app/plugins/plugin/plugin.component';
import { DatabaseService } from '../../../../src/app/database.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    PluginsModule
  ],
  providers: [AngularFirestore, DatabaseService],
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [PluginComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    customElements.define("app-component",
      createCustomElement(PluginComponent, {injector: this.injector})
    );
}
}
```

It compiles but I'm getting this error in the chrome console:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to do this, so if you have suggestions please do tell. I previously made it work but I had copy&pasted my code from the the original app to the second one, which meant I had to make my changes twice, not practical; so I'd like to import the component if that's possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the exact same problem with this scenario.

Comment: Never mind.  For me it was a broken or non-imported service reference in my sub-project.  I should have tested the component on a dummy page in the sub-project first before trying to turn it into a custom element and use it somewhere else.